# TSQL set the column value of a table variable

Tags: t-sql, field, iteration, table-variable

I am trying to set individual columns of a table variable iteratively as follows:

```
declare @reg_data table
(
    I int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Y float
)

declare @counter int, @numRows int
SET @counter = 0
SET @numRows = (select MAX(val) + 10 from tableY)

WHILE @counter < numRows
BEGIN
    SET @reg_data.Y = dbo.func1(@counter)       --HOW DO I DO THIS!!!  
    @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

The above does not work because you cannot access table variables like an array. How can I obtain the following functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set values in records that doesn't exists, so you need an `insert`:

```
WHILE @counter < numRows
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @reg_data (Y) values (dbo.func1(@counter))
    @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the completeness a one-statement example with a CTE and no looping:

```
DECLARE @reg_data TABLE (
    I INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Y FLOAT
);

WITH cteNum AS (
    SELECT MAX(val) + 10 AS val
    FROM @tableY
    HAVING MAX(val) >= 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT val-1
    FROM cteNum
    WHERE val > 0
)
INSERT @reg_data(Y)
    SELECT dbo.func1(val)
    FROM cteNum
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a cursor for this at all??

Why don't you just write some `UPDATE` statements:

```
WHILE @counter < numRows
BEGIN
    UPDATE @reg_data
    SET Y = dbo.func1(@counter)  
    WHERE I = @counter

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

You need to somehow be able to read out the *identifying* values (the `I`) from the table variable, so you can use that in your `UPDATE` statement to apply the update to exactly one row (that's identified by that value of `I`)

Comment: That is essentially what I want, but I want to iterate through I until it reaches @numRows

Comment: Looks good!! The problem is I has no values for reg_data.I yet... How can I populate reg_data.I ahead of time to be integer steps from 0 through @numRows?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: looks like Guffa's answer is probably more what you're looking for !